# Is it alright to omit either 'of' in "The survey has a margin of error of 2.5%"?

Tags: possessives

Is it alright to omit "of" in the sentence below?
There are two "of", and I mean either of them.

> The survey has a margin of error of 2.5%.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, neither of the *'of'* cannot be omitted, because an action such as that would change the meaning of the sentence or even make it meaningless.

> The survey has a margin of error of 2.5%

This means that the survey, however accurate it maybe, can have an error of 2.5% in it. Omitting the first *'of'* will convert the sentence into :

> The survey has a margin error of 2.5%.

This makes no sense as *"margin error"* is something that doesn't make sense. It is the survey that can have errors, and not the margin itself.

Omitting the second *'of'* would give the sentence a structure like:

> The survey has a margin of error 2.5%.

*"..error 2.5%"* makes no sense at all. What is *"error 2.5%"* ? I've heard of *"Error 404"*, but never an *"error 2.5%"*. So the meaning plainly becomes meaningless.

Additionally, the sentence could be rephrased without changing its meaning as:

> The survey has a marginal error of 2.5%.

But, this is something that could be interpreted in a different way too. My suggestion would be not to omit any of the *'of'* in the sentence.

Comment: Wow, what an elaborate answer! Thank you very much. It was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No.

- *Margin of error* is a well-known phrase and will sound bad if you change it.
- *Margin error* and *margin of error* are not quite equivalent in meaning.  *Margin* means "extra space at the top or side" - *margin of error* means there's "extra space" *for* an error, whereas *margin error* would mean the extra space itself *has* an error.

Comment: From your answer, I got to know "margin error" makes itself equivalent to "error of margin" which is totally different from "margin of error". Thank you for the answer. It was helpful.